# What file is crashing browserify?

Tags: browserify

With some code like this  ( there is more not shown here )

```
var inB = b.bundle()
  .on('error', function(er){
    console.log(er, er.stack);
  })
```

I get output like this ( when it fails )

```
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../glyphicon' from '/home/me/react/folder']
  stream:
   { _readableState:
      { highWaterMark: 16,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: [Object],
        pipesCount: 1,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        resumeScheduled: false },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        data: [Function: ondata],
        _mutate: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState:
      { highWaterMark: 16,
        objectMode: true,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [],
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _options: { objectMode: true },
     _wrapOptions: { objectMode: true },
     _streams: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     length: 2,
     label: 'deps' } } 

'Error: Cannot find module \'../glyphicon\' from \'/home/me/react/folder\'\n  at
 /home/me/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:55:21\n  at 
load (/home/me/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)\n  at 
onex (/home/me/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)\n  at
 /home/me/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47\n  at 
Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)\n'
```

So, I have a huge stream of browserify stuff, but though I've looked through several parts of it, I don't see anywhere that has a specific filename where the error occurred!   Is there a way to find out the filename, rather than just the folder?